# Updatepanel Repeater LinkButton OnClick Bind ListView

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I get full postbacks - I have a linkbutton in a repeater and onclick I want to bind a listview.

Both are in the same updatepanel.

This is a usercontrol not an aspx page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using umbraco.Linq.Core;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using TechReady;

public partial class usercontrols_VideoGallery : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public TechReadyDataContextDataContext techDataContext;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
            Bind_Tracks();
    }

    protected void Bind_Tracks()
    {
        techDataContext = new TechReadyDataContextDataContext();
        var tracks = from t in techDataContext.Tracks
                     orderby t.Title
                     select t;
        TracksListRepeater.DataSource = tracks;
        TracksListRepeater.DataBind();
        techDataContext.Dispose();
    }

    protected void Bind_VideoGallery(string tracktitle)
    {
        techDataContext = new TechReadyDataContextDataContext();
        var sessions = (from s in techDataContext.Sessions
                        where s.SessionTrack == tracktitle                      
                        orderby s.SessionTrack
                        select s);
        VidGalListView.DataSource = sessions;
        VidGalListView.DataBind();
        techDataContext.Dispose();
    }

    protected void TabLink_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)lb.NamingContainer;
            HtmlGenericControl litostyle2 = (HtmlGenericControl)ri.FindControl("tablinkli");
            litostyle2.Attributes.Add("Class", "ui-tabs-selected");
            Bind_VideoGallery(lb.CommandArgument);
    }

    protected void TracksListRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("tablink");
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);            
        }

    }

    protected void TracksListRepeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "TabClicked")
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this same issue: a linkbutton inside of a repeater inside of an update panel.  I found two solutions for performing an asynchronous post back when then linkbutton is clicked.
 1. Add the following attribute to the page directive containing the repeater & linkbutton:

`<%@ page ClientIDMode="AutoID" %>`
 2. Use the ScriptManager  on the databind event for the repeater:

`LinkButton linkButton = e.Item.FindControl("button") as LinkButton;
ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(linkButton)`

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 scriptmanagers running - one on a master page...